# Create a tool in javascript to insert a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, href

I need to create a tool in javascript in order to ease the creation of "

What I need is this :

1) Click on the button "create a new link" > a popup appears containing a text input like this :

> " please name the link you want to create (e.g : Link to Google) "

2) Click on OK makes a second popup appear with a second input :

> " please insert the URL you want to link (e.g : www.google.fr) "

I'm pretty sure this kind of javascript has existed for many years but I can't find the source of such a code. Any one got the answer ?

Comment: `window.prompt('please name the link you want to create');​​
window.prompt('please insert the URL you want to link');` happy coding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function createNewLink(){
  var title = prmpt('please name the link you want to create (e.g : Link to Google)');
  var href = prompt('please insert the URL you want to link (e.g : www.google.fr) ');
  document.write('<a href="'+href+'">'+title+'</a>');
}
```